# How to make sure the child of a display: inline-flex element doesn't expand its width to 100%

Tags: css

I am making an injection script on Google news and I want to put a span into its article with expanding width to 100% of the parent element:

```css
article {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>
    <a href="./articles/CAIiEIt3t6r5_e3YaJax0AEI2jwqGQgEKhAIACoHCAow2Nb3CjDivdcCMJ-thQY?hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;ceid=US%3Aen">New Yorkers ordered to mostly stay inside to fight coronavirus: 'We're all under quarantine now,'
      Gov. Cuomo says</a>
  </h3>
  <span style="cursor: copy; border: 1px solid black; padding: 0px 10px; font-size: 14px;">share</span>
</article>
```

The above code does not work. The only ways are to set a fix width OR throw the span into a div either of them would not be desirable.

Rule: you may never change `article`'s display from `inline-flex` to something else. You may only change `article > span`'s style.

Comment: Do you have to use `inline-flex` on the article? You could instead use `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` if you want it to fill the parent's width.

Comment: provide a working fiddle or snippet

Comment: @j-petty it's an injection script so it is for the best to not modify the original content

Comment: @Paulie_D I already did. You may also go on https://news.google.com/ and inspect the element (news links).

Comment: How to make sure the child of a display: inline-flex element doesn't expand its width to 100% @Paulie_D

Comment: The button is supposed to shrink to the size based on its content not the parent element.

Comment: You may not set a fix width to the button. BTW.

Comment: OR throw the span into a div.

Comment: And you may only change the css on the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `align-self` on the `span`

```
span {
align-self:flex-start;
}
```

```css
article {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>
    <a href="./articles/CAIiEIt3t6r5_e3YaJax0AEI2jwqGQgEKhAIACoHCAow2Nb3CjDivdcCMJ-thQY?hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;ceid=US%3Aen">New Yorkers ordered to mostly stay inside to fight coronavirus: 'We're all under quarantine now,'
      Gov. Cuomo says</a>
  </h3>
  <span style="cursor: copy; border: 1px solid black; padding: 0px 10px; font-size: 14px;">share</span>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow up: what if the parent element's display is "grid"?

Comment: That's a different question. It will depend on what settings you have on the parent.

Comment: Pretty much the same except the display is changed to grid: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=uOMPPd7P5d

Comment: justify-self: start;